# How to pass parameter to a function when I don't know the type

Tags: c++, qt

I made a function that is supposed to fill cell from a QTableWidget. To this function, I pass in parameter the row and `the object`. Here's the prototype of my function :

```
void remplirCaseDonnee(int myData, int row);
```

My problem is : my paramter `int myData` can now be an `int`, a `bool`, or an `enum`.

How can I do ? There's of course the solution of making 3 functions but it will be just copy paste of a lot of code.

Comment: Pass as an object and check the type at run time.

Comment: @Kangkan And what "object" would that be?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil: I hope you got how to check the type of an object from so many nice answers that can lead you further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid copy and paste, [templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) are probably what you want.

```
template <typename T> void remplirCaseDonnee(T myData, int row);
```

Comment: How could is use myData in a switch then ? For check the typeof myData.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil, Use [`typeid(T).name()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility would be to use a `QVariant` for myData, for example:

```
void remplirCaseDonnee(QVariant const& myData, int row)
{
  switch (myData.type())
  {
    case QVariant::Int:
    case QVariant::String:
    // ...
  }
}
```

And don't forget it is possible to use `boost` alongside `Qt`, so that `Boost.Any` and `Boost.Variant` could also be used.

Comment: Use Qt library is good, should I call the function like this :
remplirCaseDonnee(&data,10) ?

Comment: Maybe it is better to pass a const reference to variant like: `void remplirCaseDonnee(const QVariant &myData, int row)` instead?

Comment: You could do that, if you wanted to pass a pointer, but you probably just want `remplirCaseDonnee(data,10)`. You will convert `data` to a `QVariant`.

Comment: @vahancho I don't get the difference

Comment: @user1095108 And in the switch, should I write :

case int :
case bool :
case enum :

Comment: @EvansBelloeil Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#Type-enum).

Comment: @user1095108 Yes so no way to check if something is an enum, but I guess I could cheat using default.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil I usually cheat using an `int`, but registering a custom type with Qt is also possible. Check [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), but it can be more involved, if you also want signals and serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
template <class T>
void remplirCaseDonnee(T myData, int row);
```

You could even use `void*`, but they are hard to use in my experience:

```
void remplirCaseDonnee(void* myData, int row);
```

and call it with:

```
remplirCaseDonnee(&myData, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 3 functions without copying implementation, e.g., like this:

```
void remplirCaseDonnee(int myData, int row) {
// Original implementation.
...
}

void remplirCaseDonnee(bool myData, int row) {
    remplirCaseDonnee(static_cast<int>(myData), row);
}

void remplirCaseDonnee(EnumType myData, int row) {
    remplirCaseDonnee(static_cast<int>(myData), row);
}
```

Comment: The OP already mentioned that. He said "There's of course the solution of making 3 functions"

Comment: @Tqn: He also said "but it will be just copy paste of a lot of code." :-)